# Definition of Least Upper Bound

Tags: real-analysis

**Definition $1$**. From my lecture note,

- Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with a upper bound and $s$ is a real number. We say that $s$ is a least upper bound of $A$ if $s$ is an upper bound of $A$ and if $b$ is any upper bound of $A$ then $s\leq b$.

**Is there a mistake? I think that last sentence is a mistake.**

**Definition $2$**. My definition of SUP:

- Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with a upper bound and $s$ is a real number. We say that $s$ is a least upper bound of $A$ if $s$ is an upper bound of $A$ and if $b$ is not a upper bound of A and $b\leq s$.

Comment: Your first definition is correct and second is slightly wrong. You should have $b <s$ in second definition.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Why should not we have $b\leq s$?

Comment: What does "if $b$ is not a upper bound of $A$ and $b\le s$" even mean? You have an "if" but no "then".

Comment: Why do you "think that last sentence is a mistake"? What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: You want to show that $s$ is a least upper bound. That means that you need to show that any other upper bound $b$ is greater than it. Otherwise, $b$ would be a lesser upper bound than $s$ which was thought to be the **least** upper bound.

Comment: Your second definition should be written as "... and if $b$ is not an upper bound of $A$ then $b < s$". The part $b \leq s$ is also fine because it includes the case $b < s$. But this causes confusion when $b = s$ because $s$ is an upper bound and $b$ is not an upper bound. So better to just write $b < s$ as the case $b = s$ will never happen.

Comment: BTW note that the term "least upper bound" is self-explanatory if you know the meaning of "upper bound". On the other hand the term "supremum" is high-brow and designed to intimidate students into thinking that it is something very very deep / difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The second definition is wrong. In particular the part that says " if $b$ is not a upper bound of A and $b\le s$." If you use this piece as your definition then you are saying that every upper bound is the least upper bound.

EX: Let $(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}$. Then we'd like to say that $1$ is the least upper bound. But as per the second definition you have, we find that $2$ is an upper bound and since $2$ is not not an upper bound the second condition you have is vacuous. Hence $2$ is a least upper bound. Which is not at all true.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the closed interval [0,1].  The definition of upper bound of this set in R is any real number, p, such that if x $\in$ [0,1], then x $\le$ p. Therefore, 1, 5, 34, anything greater than or equal to 1 is an upper bound.

The least upper bound will be the smallest upper bound of all of these.  If s is the least upper bound of this set, then it must be less than or equal to any other upper bound, b, of [0,1].

It is easy to show that s = 1.

Proof:

If x $\in$ [0,1], then 0 $\le$ x $\le$ 1. So 1 is an upper bound of [0,1].  Suppose b is an upper bound of [0,1], such that 0 < b < 1.  Then b < 2b < b + 1 < 2, which implies b < (b + 1)/2 < 1.  Thus b cannot be an upper bound of [0,1], since there exists an element of [0,1], (b + 1)/2, greater than b. Hence there is no upper bound less than 1, and s =1.